# Error when i try connect play with mysql 5.5

Tags: java, mysql, playframework-2.0

There is my configure :

```
 db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 db.default.url="jdbc:mysql:root:play2test" //Cannot connect to database [default] -> play mark this line
 db.default.user=root
 db.default.pass=123456
```

I already created play2test.mwb with MySql-workbench, i have tried other way like :

```
 db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 db.default.url="jdbc:mysql:root:play2test" 
 db.default.user="root"
 db.default.pass="123456"
```

but allways get this error : db has type STRING rather than OBJECT

in terminal :

```
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sleeping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: null
[error] application - 

! @6epj0nb4d - Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error [Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:71) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:258) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:249) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:240) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:root:play2test
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:640) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200) ~[na:1.6.0_27]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:256) ~[bonecp.jar:0.7.1.RELEASE]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:305) ~[bonecp.jar:0.7.1.RELEASE]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.maybeInit(BoneCPDataSource.java:150) ~[bonecp.jar:0.7.1.RELEASE]
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.java:112) ~[bonecp.jar:0.7.1.RELEASE]
```

I tried to uncomment at

```
ebean.default="models.*"
```

and added the sbt dependency:

```
 "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.21"
```

But it did'nt work :((((
So how can i solved it :(.

> > > Sry if my english is bad

Comment: I guess the url should be in form: "jdbc:mysql//<host-name>:<host-port>/<app-name>"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following way:

```
   db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://your_server_address:3306/play2test" 
   db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
   db.default.user=root
   db.default.pass="123456"
   db.default.host=your_server_address
```

Comment: Oh God. Specialy thank to WATTO Studios and user2420313 . I followed your way and i solved it :D

Answer (score 2):

Your connection url is formatted wrong. Try using:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/play2test"
```

And make sure you set the product dependency in /project/Build.scala, change the 5.1.25 to whatever version your mysql connector is

```
val appDependencies = Seq(

"mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.25"

)
```

And in the same file, make sure that this line is not commented

```
ebean.default="models.*"
```

Comment: i try this : #ebean.default="models.*" => but still not working :(

Comment: Uncomment it and try again, also to be sure, double check that your MySQL service is running, and that all your connection properties are enclosed in quotes, including driver and username.

Answer (score 0):

The url should be something like:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://your_server_address/play2test"
```

Comment: i try: db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:9000/play2test"  and  db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/play2test ----but it's not still working :(