# JDBC connection string not working with MySQL on Play Framework

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to build an application using Play Framework 2.2 and Scala.

I'm not very acquainted to Java environments, so I don't know exactly what's going on.

To make it work with MySql, I should configure my `conf/application.conf` like this:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password="mypass"
```

Everything seems right to me, but when I try to access it, I get this:

```
 Cannot connect to database [default]
```

Why? These information are right! The database can be found at localhost:3306/sakila.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Here is my stacktrace. It seems to be missing the mysql connector .jar file, or something like that. What should I do?

[success] Compiled in 734ms
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to obtain initial connection Sle
eping for 0ms and trying again. Attempts left: 0. Exception: null.Message:**No sui
table driver found for mysql://localhost:3306/world**
[error] application -

! @6gjp5p29b - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

```
play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [
default]]
        at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configura
tion.scala:92) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:570) ~[play_2.
10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:252) ~[pla
y-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:243) ~[pla
y-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike
.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike
.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for mysql://localhost
:3306/world
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
 ~[bonecp.jar:na]
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416) ~[bonecp.jar:na]
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.jav
a:120) ~[bonecp.jar:na]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:245) ~[pla
y-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
[error] application -

! @6gjp5p29b - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [
default]]
        at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configura
tion.scala:92) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:570) ~[play_2.
10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:252) ~[pla
y-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:243) ~[pla
y-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike
.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike
.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for mysql://localhost
:3306/world
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.obtainRawInternalConnection(BoneCP.java:363)
 ~[bonecp.jar:na]
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.<init>(BoneCP.java:416) ~[bonecp.jar:na]
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.getConnection(BoneCPDataSource.jav
a:120) ~[bonecp.jar:na]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:245) ~[pla
y-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.2.1]
```

Comment: Did you include the jdbc dependency?

Comment: Did you add the dependency for the MySQL driver?

Comment: Yep. If I didn't, shouldn't it throw me an error based on the lack of a "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" object?

I'll try to check these dependencies, maybe the problem is something like a missing/incorrect .jar or something like that. I'm at work so I cant do it right now.

Comment: I updated the question. Take a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I don't know what's going on.

I put this, and it started to work:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world"
db.default.driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
db.default.user="root"
db.default.pass="mypasswrd"
db.default.host="localhost"
```

Perhaps it needed a more detailed configuration, i just added the `db.default.host`configuration, stringified everything with `""` (I think this is not necessary, but whatever) and checked if `mysql` was listed in `play dependencies` listing. Since it was listed there (in fact it was the first entry), and the error didn't say it was a missing library, I just headed to [Error when i try connect play with mysql 5.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542943/error-when-i-try-connect-play-with-mysql-5-5) and fixed my configurations.

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the MySQL JDBC driver jar in your dependencies. [This page in the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTDependencies) shows how to add the derby driver to the dependencies. Substitute the derby coordinates with [the MySQL ones](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cmysql%7Cmysql-connector-java%7C5.1.27%7Cjar).

Comment: Well, I already had it... 
`libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27"`

I even tried to create a `lib` folder and put the mysql jar into it, but no success...